# Ideal BibTeX style for urls and case sensitivity

Tags: bibtex, citing, urls, uppercase

I have several websites that I want to cite as well as wanting dois/arXiv addresses be clickable. I also want to retain the case sensitivity that I enter into my BibTeX entries.

I've tried using `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` with `@online{}` entries, but I don't like the [Online] that appears, and it doesn't add the date of access or the date of publication:

[image]

I also have to explicitly keep the case sensitivity like so:
`title = {Shedding {L}ight on {X}17 {C}onference},`.

What's the neatest way to cite urls, show publication and access dates and retain case sensitivity in bibtex?

Comment: well if you are free to choose, I would suggest biblatex + biber and not bibtex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer would you mind posting a MWE?

Answer (score -1):

You were very close, I tried and it works to just use one set of additional parenthesis instead of each individual letters:  `title = {{Shedding Light on X17 Conference}},`.